# Alertify in Button

Tags: javascript, alertify

How to show an alert when an input is empty?

Here's the code..

```
function rfc_vacio(){
  if ($('#RFC_v').val() == "") {
        alert("Empty");
        $('#RFC_v').focus();
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
}
```

i want to changue to alerfity,im new on bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

```
function rfc_vacio(){
  if ($('#RFC_v').val() == "") {
     alertify.alert("Input is empty", function(){
         alertify.message('OK');
     });
        $('#RFC_v').focus();
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
}
```

alert converted to alertify, make sure you read examples on your new javascript framework http://alertifyjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Get jQuery to trigger on the input changing

```
$('#my-input').change(function() {
    if ($('#RFC_v').val() == "") {
        alertify.alert("Empty", function(){
         alertify.message('Whatever');
     });
     $('#RFC_v').focus();
  }
});
```